# How can I test proxy calls in Shopify in development mode?

Tags: proxy, shopify

I signed up for the partner program and created a "Dev Shop" for testing purposes. I have registered an App and configured the proxy settings, but since the App isn't published I can't see how to activate it in my Dev shop. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set up an install page on your App that will generate the Authorization request for your app.

Effectively you'd take in their myshopify url. If you are using omniauth it's pretty straightforward to integrate -- https://github.com/Shopify/omniauth-shopify-oauth2

Take a look at the example app to see how it's done

Comment: Thanks - I've been experimenting with the Java library that I think you created, but CRest doesn't support OAuth2, right?

Comment: I think it does, but you need to get your credentials.  We didn't add that code in since it really wasn't needed back in the day. You'll probably need to make a new Credential implementation that prepares the CRest client for the oAuth session.  I believe there's some oAuth java libraries out there, but I haven't used any of them.

Comment: Thanks yeah - got that working, but found that the validation of the proxy callbacks and webhooks use the HMAC Sha256 encryption method which I had to implement myself.